# Laravel Nova 4 BelongsTo Depends

Tags: laravel-nova

I have two tables, Category and Product, and i set the gategory id into product. In my order page i wanna select the product base on what i have been choose in Category.

There is my code and it does not work in laravel nova 4

```
BelongsTo::make('Category', 'category', Category::class)
    ->displayUsing(function ($category) {
    return $category->name;
}),
BelongsTo::make('Product', 'product', Product::class)
    ->options(function ($query, $resource) {
    return $query->where('category_uuid', $resource->uuid);
}),
```